# Omitting null values in a php query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have a from that outputs a list of variables to an encoded URL in Joomla that should then return a result when the model runs a mySQL query.

The issue is, the user might input a null value in the search query which causes the form to return: `mysite.com/index.php?option=com_mycom&view=myview&price=1000&city=&state=`

I figure I'll need to have my form run a script that does not `POST/GET` inputs that have no value.

However, when getting the mySQL query together, I'm running in to some syntax trouble.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$query = "
        SELECT *
            FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')."
            WHERE "
                .if ($zip > 0)
                    {.$db->nameQuote('MSTZIP')." = ".$db->quote($zip)."}
                else {
                }.
                .if ($city != null)
                    { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTCITY')." LIKE ".$db->quote($city)."}
                else {
                }.
                .if ($bdrms != null)
                    { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTBDRMS')." > ".$db->quote($bdrms)."}
                else {
                }.
                .if ($bths != null)
                    { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTBATHS')." > ".$db->quote($bths)."}
                else {  
                }.
                .if ($lprice != null, $hprice != null)
                    { AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTLISTPRC')." BETWEEN ".$db->quote($lprice)." AND ".$db->quote($hprice)."}
                else {
                }.
        ; 
";
```

Am I wrong on the operators between the `IF` statements?  Am I just missing something in my syntax?

Also, if you have a reference on how to debug PHP, it would be much appreciated.  Something like JSfiddle, but for PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

syntax aside your logic flow is flawed in the sense that if the user omits a zip, the statement will read `WHERE AND...` which will fail.  That problem can be fixed by using `WHERE 1=1` and then prefixing each other conditional with `AND`.

your `if` statements also can do without the `else` that follows if they are blank.  this is not an error just not needed.

also, the last `if` statement has two conditions, I assume they are `AND`.  you should use the `&&` notation.  i.e. `if(this==true && that==true)`

finally, not in any order, other than the order I notice.  You concatenate your `if` statements, that is not needed.  Again not an error in this case I think.  Just not needed.  Actually it may be causing an error.  Consider the following:

```
$query = "
    SELECT *
        FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__mls')."
        WHERE 1 = 1 "
            .if ($zip > 0){."
                AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTZIP')." = ".$db->quote($zip)
            }
            if ($city != null){."
                AND ".$db->nameQuote('MSTCITY')." LIKE ".$db->quote($city)
            }
            // on and on like this perhaps

        ."; 
    "; // closes the string
```

I am in no way endorsing this type of flow, it gets complicated very quickly.

to debug perhaps show the error that you receive.